# How to split a string at some non-printable-character delimiter?

Tags: zsh

I know that if `$VAR` contains some string, I can split this string at, say, periods, to produce an array, like this:

```
% VAR=$ZSH_VERSION
% parts=(${(s:.:)VAR})
% printf '%s\n' $parts
5
0
7
```

What must I put between the `:` in the `(s::)` flag in order to split the value of `$VAR` at characters with ASCII code 0, say?

I've tried everything I can think of.  E.g.

```
% VAR=$'5\0000\0007'
% parts=(${(s:\000:)VAR})
% printf '%s\n' $parts
5^@0^@7
```

None of it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `p` flag to make other [expansion flags](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#index-flags_002c-parameter-expansion) (follow `p`)  recognize the escape sequence:

```
$ printf '%s\n' ${(ps:\0:)VAR}
5
0
7
```

or using the shorthand:

```
printf '%s\n' ${(0)VAR}
```

To preserve empty elements:

```
printf '%s\n' "${(0@)VAR}"
```

but you can't use that for output from `find ... -print0`, because it added trailing `\0` to output, you will always get the last empty element.

Comment: Or `"${(0@)VAR}"` to preserve empty elements (note however that you can't use that on the output of `find -print0` as it would add an empty last element because of the trailing `\0`).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks, added to the answer.